# How to ignore modifiers when invoking methods on run-time - JAVA

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I want to look for a specific annotation of every method in a class and if a method with that annotation is found, i would like to invoke it.
Also, if it's not found in the current class, a check on all inheriting classes should be made.

**My problem is that there might be some methods that are protected, private etc. and I would like to ignore those modifiers and to gain access to all methods (i.e even if it's private etc.)**

So this is how I invoke (given is the name of the annotation that I'm looking for:

```
if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Given.class)) {
        m.invoke(instObj, intArgument);
 }
```

(And this is how I check the rest of the class hierarchy - if i made a mistake somewhere, enlighten me please:

```
Class<?> superC = c.getSuperclass();
while (!(superC.equals(Object.class))) {
                handleGiven(instObj, superC, methods, currentSentence,
                        methodArgument);
```

when `handleGiven` is a recursive call.

Comment: Are you looking for [`getDeclaredMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--)?

Comment: I used getMethods, actually.

Comment: shit I guess you're right. is there an easy non recursive way to check all the inherting classes methods, as well?

Comment: `getMethods` returns only the public ones; `getDeclaredMethods` returns all of them.

Comment: can't believe it was that stupid. what about the non recursive way - u have any idea?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to check without calling `getDeclaredMethods` on every class.  There are ways to make it non-recursive (e.g. use a queue to hold the classes you need to check), but it probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Actually, I can't tell what your `while` loop is doing, since I only see part of it--it must be modifying `superC` somewhere, but how?  So it could be that you don't need recursion at all, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [getDeclaredMethods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()) to get all the methods (public, protected, etc), like this:

```
public Method findMethodWithAnnotation(Class<?> clazz,
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And check like this:

```
    Class<?> clazz = ..; //get the class
    Method m = null;
    do {
        m = findMethodWithAnnotation(clazz, DesiredAnnotation.class);
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    } while (m == null && clazz != null);
    System.out.println(m);
```

Also make sure that your annotation has the following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
```

If you need the annotation for fields, check the [getDeclaredFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()), and similars methods.

You need to make the method accessible, before the invocation

```
m.setAccessible(true);
```

---

If you want a more compact and recursive implementation, you can change to:

```
public Method findMethodWithAnnotation(Class<?> clazz,
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {

    if (clazz == Object.class || clazz == null) return null;
    for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return findMethodWithAnnotation(clazz.getSuperClass(), annotation);
}
```

And the use is:

```
Method m = findMethodWithAnnotation(clazz, DesiredAnnotation.class)
if (m == null) log("Nor the class, or any superclass have the desired annotation")
else {
    m.setAccessitble(true);
    m.invoke(obj, arguments);
}
```

#### Considerations:

- **this don't cover interfaces**, if you need to cover interfaces, check [getInterfaces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()) (this method return the interfaces in the order of declaration).
- If a a class `A` has a override method `desiredMethod`, with no annotation, and extends a class `SuperA`, witch has a method `desiredMethod`, with the desired annotation, this return `SuperA#desiredMethod`, but when you invoke it, it will invoke in the `A` class (like a normal invocation)

Comment: Does this mean that my impl. is wrong or it's just another solution (for the recursive part)

Comment: No, your solution is not wrong, this is only the complete implentation.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that there might be some methods that are protected, private etc. and I would like to ignore those modifiers and to gain access to all methods (i.e even if it's private etc.)

You need to call [`Method.setAccessible(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) before invoking it, not forgetting to restore its original value afterwards, in a finally block.